# Average Minutes Viewed Facebook metric

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, average

Run into a situation that cannot figure out how to extract with FB API Average Video Minutes (or seconds,or milliseconds) Viewed. I tried self made formula with pyhton - total time in ms divide by total 3s views and divide by 1000 ms as I need answer in sec:

```
total_video_view_total_time / total_video_views / 1_000
```

My result (took first video from the list as a test) is about ~ 90 seconds, but the result is not the same as if look through video activity in Facebook:

[image]

Where is my mistake, how FB calculates this vital metric ?

Comment: Why are you trying to calculate this yourself, when the API offers the metric `total_video_avg_time_watched`?

Comment: I thought it gives Total Count, not ms. You mean I need total_video_avg_time_watched / 1_000 and that's it ? 54378/1000 = 54,378, OMG, it is so obvious, thank you !

Comment: But I am still curious, why  total_video_view_total_time / total_video_views / 1_000 not giving the same ?

Comment: Probably because `total_video_views` only includes views > 3 seconds.